# howto dismiss or swipe action a row inside data table?

Tags: flutter

i hava a dataTable what i want to do is when i swip a row to the left it shows an icon on the right and when i click on it i can delete it .like the image . this is my code : i add it on the function onSelectChanged: SwipeActionCell() but it doesn't work . Also i can't use Dissimible because it needs a child .
this the code :
[image]

```
Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: DataTable(
                          showCheckboxColumn: false,
                          columnSpacing: unitWidthValue * 0.021,
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Center(
                              child: Text('number',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                          tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                      fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                            )),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Center(
                              child: Text('name',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                          tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                      fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                            )),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Center(
                              child: Text('date ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                          tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                      fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                            )),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('')),
                          ],
                          rows: widget.persons
                              .map((person) => DataRow(
                                    cells: <DataCell>[
                                      DataCell(Text(person.number)),
                                      DataCell(SizedBox(
                                        width: unitWidthValue * 0.35,
                                        child: Text(person.sampleNumber,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize:
                                                    unitWidthValue * 0.035,
                                                fontFamily:
                                                    "SF Pro Display")),
                                      )),
                                      DataCell(Text(person.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:
                                                  unitWidthValue * 0.035,
                                              fontFamily:
                                                  "SF Pro Display"))),
                                      DataCell(Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: unitHeightValue * 0.02),
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            if (person.status ==
                                                    personStatus
                                                        .recorded ||
                                                person.status ==
                                                    personStatus.associate)
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.save,
                                                color: Color(0xFF0061B0),
                                              )
                                            else if (person.status ==
                                                personStatus.transmitted)
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.check_circle,
                                                color: Color(0xFF34C759),
                                              )
                                            else
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.warning,
                                                color: Color(0xFFFF9500),
                                              )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                    ],
                                    onSelectChanged: (bool? isDispalyData) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                          PageRouteBuilder(
                                            pageBuilder: (context,
                                                    animation1,
                                                    animation2) =>
                                                DisplayData(person,
                                                    isDisplayData: true),
                                            transitionDuration:
                                                Duration.zero,
                                            reverseTransitionDuration:
                                                Duration.zero,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ))
                              .toList()),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            )
```